# Not able to mock a method with List type argument

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit4

I have a method like this

```
public int[] processData(List<Data> dataList){
    //business logic
}
```

And I have used the following way to mock it

```
when(processData(anyList())).thenReturn(new int[]{1,1});
```

and

```
when(processData(Mockito<Data>.anyList())).thenReturn(new int[]{1,1});
```

but nothing works.

I am using spring boot with Java 11 and Mockito 3.1

Is there any other way to mock the same?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing works"? What happens?

Answer (score 0):

**Mockito** leverages `equal()` as legacy method for verification/matching of argument values.

In some cases, user needs more flexibility during the verification of argument values, so it's better to use argument matchers instead of `equal()` method.

Note :

1. eq(obj) checks that the argument equals obj according to its equals method. This applies even if you pass real values without using matchers.
2. `equals()` method demands that for two lists to be equal, they must contain same elements in the same order.
3. In case of two list, Type of your lists should match.

Refer to doc for details : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyList;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class Test {

    @Mock
    A a;

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    public void t1() {
        when(a.processData(anyList())).thenReturn(new int[]{1,1});
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.processData(new ArrayList<>())));
    }
}
interface Data {}
interface A {
     int[] processData(List<Data> dataList);
}
```

This prints: `[1, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use when(processData(mock(List.class)).thenReturn(new int[]{1,1}) but your variant when(processData(anyList())).thenReturn(new int[]{1,1}) works for me too.